# What does it mean if Host is empty in an HTTP get message?

Tags: javascript, networking

If an HTTP GET message doesn't have a specified host:, does mean it's the localhost?

```
GET /HelloUser.jsp?name=John HTTP/1.1<cr><lf>Host: <cr><lf>User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv: ) Gecko/ Firefox/<cr><lf>Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.<cr><lf>Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5<cr><lf>Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate <cr><lf>Accept-Charset: ISO ,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7<cr><lf>Keep-Alive: 300<cr><lf>Connection: keep-alive<cr><lf><cr><lf>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that means whatever client you're using to perform the HTTP GET is not setting that header. If you send an HTTP request using curl or your web browser, it's usually set for you. You can actually set it to anything you want.

```
# send request to localhost, but ask for "example.com"
curl -H "Host: example.com" http://localhost:8080
```

I don't think you need to worry about it unless your web server relies on it for something (ex. reverse proxying).